# Facebook API v6 : search groups by name

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

I want to search the list of groups by name or group id.I have a problem in the FQL and the Access token.if anyone can help me.

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
        dynamic result = fb.Get("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = Cid,
            client_secret = Sid,
            grant_type = "client_credentials"

        });
        fb.AccessToken = result.access_token;
        var fb1 = new FacebookClient(fb.AccessToken);
        fb.Get("https://graph.facebook.com/search?fields=name&q=GroupName&type=group");
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?